# selecting from 2 database table to display

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

i have two tables:

```
    products
id  | name  |  brand  |  desc
 1   pencil   brand1     desc1
 2   paper    brand2     desc2
 3   books    brand1     desc3
 4   pen      brand2     desc4
 5   crayons  brand1     desc5
```

and:

```
    supplier
id  | name  |  brand
 1    sup1     brand1
 2    sup2     brand2
```

how will i display all products and information associated with the `brand1` under `supplier brand`

for example:if the supplier `brand1` wants to view all products, he will see this information:

I'd expect this kind of result

```
    products
id  | name  |  brand  |  desc
 1   pencil   brand1     desc1
 3   books    brand1     desc3
 5   crayons  brand1     desc5
```

do i need to join query? is there much simpler way? I just hope someone will help me with this, im currently using php and phpmyadmin, any form of code will do as long as it will display the specific result under supplier table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id try this

Answer (score 0):

A simple left join would do the trick.
Something like this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.brand, p.desc, s.name  FROM products p
LEFT JOIN supliers s ON s.brand = p.brand
```

Although I would use ID columns for both tables to link data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing like,

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.brand, p.desc, s.name  FROM products p LEFT JOIN supliers s ON s.brand = p.brand
```